# Datatable does not print all my rows on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I am trying to get rows from back-end response on each scroll. I get 
an AJAX response, but I can't get full row, it eats up the data
most probably the last one.

I tried with so other alternative, but it's not working at all, I tried redraw and reload in AJAX.

Here goes my js code:

```
  var table= $('#subscriber_list').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "processing":true,
        serverSide: true,
        "scrollCollapse":true,
        "sDom":"BifrtS",
        scrollY:'35vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:false,
        "oScroller": {
            "displayBuffer": 2,"loadingIndicator": true
        },
        "ajax": {"url": $('#data_table_column_list').attr("url"),"type": 'POST',"data":{'type':subscriber_type,'end_date_from':end_date_from,'end_date_to':end_date_to}},
        "columns": JSON.parse($('#data_table_column_list').val().replace(/\'/g, '"')),
        "columnDefs": [
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                text: 'Export selected',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible:not(.not-exported)',
                    modifier: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                },
                title: 'Data export'
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                text: 'Export All',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible:not(.not-exported)'
                },
                title: 'Data export'
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: it displays 10 rows out of 11 ,11th entry is eaten up  :( , i m using multiple table rendering using same script

Comment: I see `paging` is set to `false`, have you set the page length? It is usually 10 by default

Answer (score 0):

You need one or both of the following depending on how you want the table to work.

Right now, it's getting cut off because the default in Datatables is 10 rows. You have paging set to `false`, so any results after the 10th are now shown.

Either switch this: `paging:false,`

to: `paging:true,`

That'll give you multiple pages of results with 10 on each page.

You can also add `"pageLength": 50` or some other value if you want more than 10 rows per page.

Comment: thank you sir,

pagging problem is gone, but again got stuck with the other one

Answer (score 0):

here i am using same data table from multiple radio button switch, on switching  i get warning from data table  can't be re-initialised , since i know when i use table.destroy(); it destroy's all the object's created at while i switch the options, but have alternate to use it , what to do now ???? , running out of idea
i was referring this actually
https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3

```
 $('.subscriber_type').on('change',function (e){ 
     var table = $('#subscriber_list').DataTable();
    subscriber_data_table($(this).val(),$('#datepicker_from').val(),$('#datepicker_to').val());
});

 subscriber_data_table("all",null,null);

   function  subscriber_data_table(subscriber_type,end_date_from,end_date_to) {
    $('#subscriber_list').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "processing": true,
        serverSide: true,
        paging:true,
        "pageLength":50,
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            console.log( 'hit began' );
        },
        "sScrollY": "379",
        "sDom":"BifrtS",
        "oScroller": {
            "displayBuffer": 2,"loadingIndicator": true
        },
        "ajax": {"url": $('#data_table_column_list').attr("url"),"type": 'POST',"data":{'type':subscriber_type,'end_date_from':end_date_from,'end_date_to':end_date_to}},
        "columns": JSON.parse($('#data_table_column_list').val().replace(/\'/g, '"')),
        "columnDefs": [
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                text: 'Export selected',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible:not(.not-exported)',
                    modifier: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                },
                title: 'Data export'
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                text: 'Export All',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible:not(.not-exported)'
                },
                title: 'Data export'
            }
        ]
    });
}
```